# Is it ok to use double pointer output parameters when return value is occupied?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I'm trying to implement a simple GetOrCreate() method - get an object by key, or create a new one if not already exists. So far no brainer. I also would like my function's return value to be a `Status`. So I created the following:

```
Status GetOrCreate(KeyType key, ObjectType* object) {
  Status s = OK;
  decltype(my_map)::iterator iter;
  bool inserted_new;
  std::tie(iter, inserted_new) = clients_.insert(key, ObjectType(...));
  if (inserted_new) {
    // s = ... Initialize the new ObjectType ...
  }
  *object = iter->second;
  return s;
}
```

And calling the function:

```
ObjectType result(...);
Status s = GetOrCreate(key, &result);
```

Now, I feel it's somewhat wasteful, because:

1. There is an unnecessary copy in `*object = iter->second;`
2. There is an unnecessary object initialization in `ObjectType result(...)`;

(Not sure. I may be wrong, or perhaps c++11 elides them. Still I would like to explicitly know what I'm doing).

So I created a version #2 which passes `ObjectType** object` instead. I'm not afraid of double pointers but might require more explaining to my reviewers. `*&` is not an option due to [project code-style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments).

Seems like a very basic design problem, but I'm scratching my head. So, is it justified to use double pointer here? Is there a better approach?

I'm using C++11 (most of my experience is 98).

Comment: Any reason you can't return a struct with both the status and the pointer?

Comment: (1) Use `emplace`, cut the middle-man. (2) Why not do as UKMonkey said? Maybe even as the standard library does `std::pair<Status, ObjectType>`. (3) Btw, are you sure you want to return a copy?

Comment: IMO: regarding https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments - try to change this rule - it is well... maybe I won't exactly say what I think about it...

Comment: @StoryTeller (2) I'll consider that (currently I prefer not to because the current class I'm enhancing has most his methods return Status, and I find it very elegant) . Either way I still would like an answer to the X. (3) If you are asking about Status the answer is yes. If you are asking about the object I definitely want NOT TO return a copy.

Comment: @PiotrNycz - You don't have to. [Someone already did](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273767/cubbi).

Comment: @PiotrNycz Would be hard to change :) Google is a big company :)

Comment: @UKMonkey Currently I prefer not to because the current class I'm enhancing has most his methods return Status, and I find it very elegant.

Comment: @EladWeiss - I'd rather not start a debate about elegance. Error statuses are rarely adhered to properly... so whatever. Anyway, as long as the return value is hogged, you don't have too many options. Maybe a `boost::optional`? That way at least the caller doesn't have to default construct an `Object` (an anti-pattern).

Comment: If your existing method styles is to return status, then you have no choice when you want to return more info than to use a pointer to caller storage, but I would add it as a third argument, which is optional and could be NULL from the caller.

The loss of return semantics to statuses was part of why exceptions were invented, though.

Emplace can help you get the data into the map without constructing the empty or the copy, but you may need the piecewise_construct pair complication to be able to index your map without first constructing the map object.

Answer (score 0):

How about using smart pointers:

```
std::pair<Status, std::shared_ptr<ObjectType>> GetOrCreate(KeyType key) {
  Status s = OK;
  decltype(my_map)::iterator iter;
  bool inserted_new;
  std::tie(iter, inserted_new) = clients_.insert(key, ObjectType(...));
  if (inserted_new) {
    // s = ... Initialize the new ObjectType ...
  }
  return std::pair<Status, std::shared_ptr<ObjectType>>(s, iter->second);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
auto ret = GetOrCreate(key, result);
// ret->first is Status
// ret->second is std::shared_ptr<ObjectType>
```